# String encoding issue in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding

In ruby 1.9.3-p484 I have to construct an SMPP package, but when I pass the constructed packet's content in string to the method that delivers it, a strange `\xC2` value appears in the content. Having investigated the issue, I found the following interesting gotcha:

```
"\u008E".force_encoding("BINARY")
 => "\xC2\x8E"
```

Why does `\u00BE` become `\xC2\8E` when I want to use binary encoding? Why not `\x00\x8E`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is just forces text in [binary](/questions/tagged/binary) encoding, and you have seen it as it is stored in memory. And it is stored in memory as an [mbcs](/questions/tagged/mbcs)(Multi-Byte Character Set) data. And for chars over `\x7F` it become at leat two-bytes representation. So you can see:

```
"\u008E".force_encoding("BINARY")
# => "\xC2\x8E"
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a binary representation.
 Take a look:

> > At Tue, 27 Jul 2010 22:21:31 +0900, Heesob Park wrote in :
>
> I noticed String#inspect results \x{XXXX} for the encoding other than
>   Unicode.
>
> Is there any possibility that \x{XXXX} is accepted as an escape
>   sequence of string?
>
> irb(main):004:0> a = "\xC7\xD1\xB1\xDB"
>
> This is in binary representation.
>
> irb(main):010:0> a[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)
>   => "\x{B1DB}"

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3619

It's on a [codepoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) representation.